# In MIPS32, when load address is called does the register receive all 4 addresses of the variable?

Tags: assembly, mips32, spim, qtspim

Assuming I have a variable which is a word, if I were to call

```
la $t0, var
```

Would the register now store 4 different addresses or just one?

I am lost in regards to this as all the programming guides show that words are stored in 4 different 8 byte memory locations, yet when calling load address all the guides seem to only reference one single address being passed. If it is just one address, how is it referenced?

Comment: Primitive values and simple data structures are normally placed in contiguous byte ranges. It suffices to know the address of the first allocated byte, the remaining addresses are derived through simple arithmetics.

Answer (score 1):

`$t0` will contain the address of the first *byte* of `var`, because a byte is the smallest addressable unit of memory on most CPUs. Whether you want to treat that address as the address of a byte (`lb`/`lbu`/`sb`), a halfword (`lh`/`lhu`/`sh`), or a word (`lw`/`sw`) is up to you.

(Note that whether the first byte is the most significant or the least significant byte of the word depends on the byte order used by the particular CPU model).